# Existence Of Solution Of Congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The $q$-cyclotomic coset of $a$ modulo $n$ is the set $C_a = \{a, aq, aq^2, \dots, aq^{t_a - 1}\}$, where $t_a$ is the smallest integer such that $a q^{t_a} \equiv a \mod n$. I would like to know when a specific number is an element of a given $q$-coset (for short). For example, the $2$-coset $C_{11} = \{11, 13, 21, 22, 26\}$ modulo $31$, so I could ask when $2^x \cdot 11 \equiv 21 \mod 31$ if I wanted to see if $21$ is in the $2$-coset generated by $11$. This specific question can be solved by using primitive roots.

I would like to know what's the most general existence statement that can be made about $a q^x \equiv b \mod n$, where $q$ is a prime and $a, b$ are $0 < a, b < n$, and $n$ is not necessarily prime.